# Why isn't my rss feed working that I have coded in XML?

Tags: xml, rss

Here is the [link](http://nicolaelvin.com/authoring/nicolaElvinsPortfolio.xml) to it.  It's only showing the title field, but as far as I can see the rest is right.  It must be something to do with the image I have added because that seems to be where it stops working.  I have added a screenshot of the xml tree.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out, it's because you can only have image nodes inside the channel, not in the items.